# Creating a custom WHERE clause for filtering datatables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am working with datatables, and I am trying to create a custom WHERE clause. I have the following code:

```
$sWhere = "WHERE office=".$varOffice;
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ') AND office='.$varOffice;
}
```

After debugging, I discovered MySQL was throwing an error. Error 1605.

I decided to echo the `$sQuery` found here:

```
$sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
```

I then found out that the error was because the WHERE clause did not have quotes as in:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `amount_due_owed`, `amount_paid`, `amount_remaining`, `reference_number` FROM accounting WHERE office=Office 1
```

It is supposed to be:

```
WHERE office='Office 1'
```

I have been trying and I haven't been able to figure it out. How am I supposed to get the single quotes around the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Add the single quotes in your first line:

```
$sWhere = "WHERE office='".$varOffice."'";
```

Also: If you just go around inserting random `$_GET` variables into your SQL queries, you're eventually going to have a [bad time](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection). Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) or something a little safer (even `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not that safe.).

Comment: This is the way, but can get really messy, if there is a lot of this sort of thing "here" statements using <<<QEND ... QEND;  can be very handy as they allow both ' and " within the content.

Comment: Very true... But the real answer is prepared statements :)

Comment: Prepared statements are always best where possible. Sometimes  when you need to build a statement conditionally or especially iteratively you can't use them easily because you have no idea how many parameters you will have.